# What is the equivalent ant command for export as EAR file and welogic deploy and undeploy command?

Tags: ant

I am trying to create a hudson job to perform build of my application.

I like to checking on the following

- equivalent ant command for export as EAR file
- equivalent ant command for deploy / undeploy for weblogic portal EAR file deployment

Answer (score 1):

To create ear, you would want to use [ant ear task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html).

To deploy in weblogic, you should look at [wldeploy ant task](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/wldeploy.html)